# Set multiple tfrecord into config file of Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, tfrecord

I have several tfrecord splited into 5 shards

ex)
train-1.tfrecord
train-2.tfrecord
train-3.tfrecord
train-4.tfrecord
train-5.tfrecord

And I want to use all tfrecord.

My detection model is Faster-rcnn(resnet101)

ex)
models/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101.config

can I use like this?

..
input_path: "/path/to/train-*.tfrecord"
..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) in the file path that you give (or paths, since you can give more than one too). Although I couldn't find explicit documentation about it, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/v1.13.0/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py#L61), you can see that the input paths are expanded with [`tf.gfile.Glob`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/gfile/Glob):

```py
filenames = tf.gfile.Glob(input_files)
```

So your example should work as expected.